# How to add URL Link to this <a class=>

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, class, widget

Creating a wordpress site, and got this within the widget section...can't seem to get any url code to work!

This is the code at the moment;

```
[one_third]
<a class="home-buttons"><i class="icon mortgage-calculator-icon"></i>Mortgage Calculator</a>
<a class="home-buttons"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Help to Buy</a>
<a class="home-buttons"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Meet the Team</a>
<a class="home-buttons"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Contractor Mortgages</a>
<a class="home-buttons"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>FactSheets</a>
[/one_third]
```

How do I add URL functionality, so that each button links to a URL

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick, add the `href` element. Change `home.html` by any url that you wish.

```
[one_third]
    <a class="home-buttons" href="home.html"><i class="icon mortgage-calculator-icon"></i>Mortgage Calculator</a>
    <a class="home-buttons" href="home.html"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Help to Buy</a>
    <a class="home-buttons" href="home.html"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Meet the Team</a>
    <a class="home-buttons" href="home.html"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>Contractor Mortgages</a>
    <a class="home-buttons" href="home.html"><i class="icon newsletter-icon"></i>FactSheets</a>
[/one_third]
```

Comment: Hi,

Cheers, I was adding the href in before, but put it in the wrong area.

thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Anchor links usually contain an href attribute which contains the URL, for example:

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
```